# How to get number of instances in time for Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I have a website hosted on Azure and I was wondering how to get some info on the number of instances in time. I'm looking for info like this.

> User XYZ changed the number of instances from 1 to 3 on 2018-09-18 10:00

This could be very useful also when autoscaling enabled. Is this kind of info available somewhere in the Azure portal? I was looking into Activity log and there seems to be some "Update hosting plan" operation but can't read the number of instances from it.

Comment: You can see logs in kudu website of your web app.

Answer (score 3):

You can view the Run History to know the numbers of instances via Scale-out (App service plan) in your App service.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also get the specific instance info via Process Explorer for web app service. Ref: [Monitoring your multiple Azure Web App instances](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2015/11/03/monitoring-your-multiple-azure-web-app-instances/)

[image]

### Update

> I'm looking for kind of audit WHO and WHEN changed the number of
>   instances. Is it at least possible to retrieve the info from some
>   logs?

As for as I know, there is not exactly the same log as you expect. WHO is not specific somebody here since Autoscale setting enabled makes **automatically** increase or decrease the number of instances for your web app service. You can configure Autoscale settings to be triggered based on metrics that indicate load or performance, or triggered at a scheduled date and time. When an autoscale rule triggers, your scale set can automatically scale in. You can see the logs from *click here to see more details* in Run history.

[image]

If you have not enabled the autoscale, you do not activate the scale rules, the scale instances will not be triggered, so there is not a log for instances changes.

Ref: [Understand Autoscale settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-understanding-autoscale-settings?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json)

Comment: Please let me know if this helps, or if I can help you further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @nancy-xiong-msft. It is indeed valid if the autoscaling is enabled. The process explorer shows the current status. Is there some way also for the scenario when the auto scale is not enabled? (to make the answer more complete)

Comment: @mivra  If the auto scale is not enabled, you also can see the current instance ID in the process explorer. There are two suggestions in my initial reply.

Comment: @nancy-xiong-msft yes, I understand. However, the process explorer shows current status, while I'm looking for information WHEN the number of instances changed.

Comment: @mivra if you have not enabled the auto scale, the instance number will  not change, if you enable the auto scale, you can see the change time in Run History and instance info in process explorer.

Comment: @mivra you also can see the run history in my first screenshot, the chart is empty until I enabled the autoscale.

Comment: @nancy-xiong-msft Still don't have an answer to whether it is possible to get the info without autoscale enabled. I'm looking for kind of audit WHO and WHEN changed the number of instances. Is it at least possible to retrieve the info from some logs?

Comment: @mivra please check my update, hope my explanation is helpful.